# SQL - Counting and Summarizing (in ranges) the number of instances of a given transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, pivot

I've got an Occurrences table that contains one row for each time a user took an action.  A user take an action multiple times per day.  It looks like this:

```
Date      Username
------    --------
1/1/9     User1
1/1/9     User1
1/1/9     User2
1/2/9     User1
1/2/9     User3
1/3/9     User1
1/3/9     User1
1/3/9     User1
1/3/9     User2
1/3/9     User3
1/4/9     User1
1/5/9     User1
1/6/9     User1
1/7/9     User1
```

For each day in the range, I'd like to show the count of people who have taken the action multiple times - let's say, between 2 and 5 times, between 6 and 10 times, and more than 10 times.  However, I *only*  consider repeating the action on a different day to count as another instance of that action.  For example, if a user did the thing 3 times on the first day and then again any # of times on the next day, I see that user has having done the action 2 times and hence should be in the 2-to-5 times column.

The result set corresponding to the above sample data would be:

```
        #_of_people       #_of_people       #_of_people       
        who_did_action    who_did_action    who_did_action        
Date    2to5_times        6to10_times       more_than_10      Total
-----   --------------    --------------    --------------    -----
1/1/9   0                 0                 0                 0
1/2/9   1                 0                 0                 1
1/3/9   3                 0                 0                 3   
...    
1/7/9   0                 1                 0                 1
```

Note that each row of the result is counting the # of repeat actions *for that specific day only* - not cumulative.

- The 1/1/9 row is all zeros since it's the first day and all actions are considered to be the first.
- The 1/2/9 row is 1, 0, 0, 1 because only User1 has repeated - it's User3's first time.
- The 1/3/9 row is 3, 0, 0, 3 because User1 has repeated twice, User2 has repeated once, and User3 has also repeated once.
- The 1/7/9 row is 0, 1, 0, 1 because User1 has repeated 6 times.

Comment: Date is datetime data type.  But I'm happy to convert between anything and everything if necessary.  :)

Comment: 2008 in this case, but any really.  Would prefer to do with non-version -specific features if possible, but if not, no worries.

Comment: How does user 1 go from repeating twice on 1/3/9 to repeating 6 times on 1/4/9? Maybe I'm dense, but I can't make any sense of your numbers.

Comment: @Tom H.: I believe the table is just logs.

Comment: @Tom - Not sure if you saw my last comment but I just deleted it.  You are absolutely right - I meant to say that the "1/7/9" row is 0, 1, 0, 1.  I've made the correction.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Best I could come up with, untested:

```
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(40)
DECLARE @date DATETIME
DECLARE @counter INT
    SET @counter = 1

WITH occur AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), o.date, 101) AS dt,
            o.username
       FROM OCCURRENCES o
   ORDER BY o.username, dt),
     occur_rank AS (
     SELECT x.dt,
            @username = x.username,
            @date = CAST(x.dt AS DATETIME),
            CASE WHEN @username = x.username AND @date + 1 = x.date THEN @counter = @counter + 1 ELSE @counter = 1 END AS rank
       FROM occur x
   ORDER BY x.username, x.dt)
  SELECT or.dt,
         SUM(CASE WHEN or.rank BETWEEN 2 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 2_to_5,
         SUM(CASE WHEN or.rank BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 6_to_10
    FROM occur_rank or
GROUP BY or.dt
```

If you can get the numbering to reset on a date gap, the rest is easy.  But [none of the SQL Server ranking functions support that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx).  So that leaves manually incrementing a variable.

The first CTE, `occur` just returns a list of usernames associated with dates.  The second CTE builds on it, adding the ranking for the final output to pivot on.

Comment: The convert is necessary to get rid of the time portion of the `DATE` column, because it is a DATETIME data type.

Comment: You read my mind.  :)  I'm trying this now.  There should be a comma after the "as dt" and an "as" between the COUNT(*) and the 'num_occur' I believe, right?

Comment: @Robert: Fixed the missing comma, thx.  `AS` isn't required for defining table aliases, but I should've been consistent.

Comment: Instead of using Case for two outcomes, use the IIF function. It's neater.

Comment: But "num_occur" is used here as a column alias, not a table alias I think?

Comment: @Tor: `CASE` is ANSI standard, supported on other databases.

Comment: @Robert: num_occur is a column alias

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Yeah, but CONVERT() isn't, so what's your point? ;)

Comment: @Tor Vaolamo: CONVERT is supported on Oracle and MySQL, besides SQL Server.

Comment: @Robert - Here's the results I'm getting from the query (only showing the 2-5 and 6-10 columns) versus what I'd expect from the data set in the question:  1/1/9 is 1, 0.  1/2/9 is 0, 0.  1/3/9 is 1, 0.  1/4/9 is 0, 0.  1/5/9 is 0, 0.  1/6/9 is 0, 0.  1/7/9 is 0, 0.

Comment: I just saw that IIF is not supported in sql server (though it is in access, which is why I thought it might work).

Comment: @Robert: Check that the user counts per day match what you expect.

Comment: @OMG - I think I see what it is.  I'm trying to return not the # of occurrences on a given day, but rather the # of *repeat occurrences* on a given day, where multiple occurrences per day don't count.  Said differently, 1/3/9 is User's 3rd day on the site, so this would add +1 to the 2-5 column for that day.  1/3/9 was also User2's 2nd day on the site (another +1 to the 2-5 column) and User3's 2nd day as well (another +1 to the 2-5 column = 3 for that day).  As another example, 1/7/9 was User1's 7th time at the site, so that puts a +1 in the 6-10 column.

Comment: @Robert: Understood.  I won't have time to update answer till later today.

Comment: @OMG - I'm going to go through what you just posted.

Answer (score 0):

I used a derived table with a correlated subquery.

The correlated subquery results in a column ActionCount that counts the number of distinct dates up to and including that row's Date for that row's Username.

The resulting derived table lists each Date, Username, and ActionCount.

The outer query then groups the results by Date, counting the number of ActionCounts between 2 and 5, between 6 and 10, greater than 10, and, for the Total, greater than 1 (an ActionCount equal to 1 is not a 'repeat').

```
select
    [Date],
    sum(case when [ActionCount] between 2 and 5 then 1 else 0 end) [#_of_people_who_did_action_2to5_times],
    sum(case when [ActionCount] between 6 and 10 then 1 else 0 end) [#_of_people_who_did_action_6to10_times],
    sum(case when [ActionCount] > 10 then 1 else 0 end) [#_of_people_who_did_action_more_than_10],
    sum(case when [ActionCount] > 1 then 1 else 0 end) [Total]
from (
    select distinct
        dt.[Date],
        dt.[Username],
        (select count(distinct [Date]) from OCCURRENCES cd where cd.[Username] = dt.[Username] and cd.[Date] <= dt.[Date]) [ActionCount]
    from OCCURRENCES dt
) a
group by [Date]
```